# C++ template to accept both const and non-const objects

Tags: c++, templates, constants

How can I get the following code to compile? I would like to support all variations of constness for the c-style array and std::array supplied to the constructor.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
class Base
{
 public:
    explicit Base(T* data) : data_(data) {}

 private:
    T* data_;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t S>
class A : public Base<T>
{
 public:
    explicit A(T (&array)[S]) : Base<T>(array) { ; }

    template <template <typename, std::size_t> class C>
    explicit A(C<T, S>& c) : Base<T>(c.begin())
    {
        ;
    }

    template <template <typename, std::size_t> class C>
    explicit A(C<T, S> const& c) : Base<T>(c.begin())
    {
        ;
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr std::size_t size{5U};
    int c_style_array[size] = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
    A<int, size> a(c_style_array);  // OK
    int const c_style_array_const[size] = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
    A<int const, size> b(c_style_array_const);  // OK

    std::array<int, size> std_array = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
    A<int, size> c(std_array);  // OK
    std::array<int const, size> std_array_const_1 = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
    A<int const, size> d(std_array_const_1);  // OK
    std::array<int const, size> const std_array_const_2 = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
    A<int const, size> e(std_array_const_2);  // OK
    std::array<int, size> const std_array_const_3 = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
    A<int, size> f(std_array_const_3);  // NOT OK
}
```

Error message:

```
*a.cpp: In instantiation of ‘A<T, S>::A(const C<T, S>&) [with C = std::array; T = int; long unsigned int S = 5]’:
a.cpp:46:37:   required from here
a.cpp:26:53: error: invalid conversion from ‘std::array<int, 5>::const_iterator {aka const int*}’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
     explicit A(C<T, S> const& c) : Base<T>(c.begin())
                                                     ^
a.cpp:7:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘Base<T>::Base(T*) [with T = int]’
     explicit Base(T* data) : data_(data) {}*
```

I would prefer a solution using [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03), but I am interested in a solution using [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) as well.

Comment: Did You try `c.data()`?

Comment: It gives the same result: error: invalid conversion 'const int*’ to ‘int*’ which is logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that works because it can be controlled what type that is used to instantiate the base class:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
template <typename T>
class Base
{
 public:
    explicit Base(T* data) : data_(data) {}

 private:
    T* data_;
};

template <typename U, std::size_t S>
class A : public Base<U>
{
 public:
    template<typename T>
    explicit A(T (&array)[S]) : Base<T>(array) { ; }

    template <typename T, template <typename, std::size_t> class C>
    explicit A(C<T, S>& c) : Base<T>(c.begin())
    {
        ;
    }

    template <typename T, template <typename, std::size_t> class C>
    explicit A(C<T, S> const& c) : Base<T const>(c.begin())
    {
        ;
    }
};
int main()
{
    constexpr std::size_t size{5U};
    int c_style_array[size] = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
    A<int, size> a(c_style_array);  // OK
    int const c_style_array_const[size] = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
    A<int const, size> b(c_style_array_const);  // OK

    std::array<int, size> std_array = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
    A<int, size> c(std_array);  // OK
    std::array<int const, size> std_array_const_1 = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
    A<int const, size> d(std_array_const_1);  // OK
    std::array<int const, size> const std_array_const_2 = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
    A<int const, size> e(std_array_const_2);  // OK
    std::array<int, size> const std_array_const_3 = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
    A<int const, size> f(std_array_const_3);  // OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following declaration

```
std::array<int, size> const std_array_const_3 = {2, 6, 7, 8, 3};
A<int, size> f(std_array_const_3);  // NOT OK
```

doesn't works because `A<int, size>` inherit from `Base<int>` that contains a `int *` and you try to initialize it with `std_array_const_3.begin()` that return a const iterator that you can roughly see as a `int const *`.

And, obviously, you can't initialize a `int *` with a `int const *`.

It seems to me that `f` should be an `A<int const, size>`, not a `A<int, size>`. Unfortunately an `A<int const, size>` can't be initialized from a `std::array<int, size> const`.

So I propose to add, in `A`, the following constructor to manage this special case

```
template <template <typename, std::size_t> class C,
          typename U = typename std::remove_const<T>::type>
explicit A(C<U, S> const & c) : Base<T>(c.begin())
 { }
```

This solution uses `std::remove_const`, that is available starting from C++11, but I suppose you can easily create a substitute for it in C++98/C++03.

An alternative could be modify the `C<T, S> const &` constructor to match both cases as follows

```
template <typename U, template <typename, std::size_t> class C,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U const, T const>, bool> = true>
explicit A(C<U, S> const & c) : Base<T>(c.begin())
 { }
```

Also for `std::enable_if_t` and `std::is_same_v`, I suppose you should be able to construct C++98/C++03 alternative.